# Swift extension method not accessible in Cpp using interop

Tags: c++, swift, interop

I have a project implementing new interop mechanism and I m able to successfully invoke swift class method directly from swift. However, when I try to invoke the swift extension method it produces an error : No member named 'GetExtData' in 'InteropExtension::SwiftCode'

Below is my cpp code:

```
#include "CppSource.hpp"
#include "InteropExtension-Swift.h"

void CppSource::CppToSwiftCall()
{
    // successfull call
    InteropExtension::SwiftCode::GetClassData();
    
    //Below call is causing error. Why is swift extension method not invoked?
    InteropExtension::SwiftCode::GetExtData();

}
```

Below is my swift code:

```
import Foundation


public class SwiftCode {
    
    public static func GetClassData () -> String
    {
        return "classMethod"
    }
        
}

extension SwiftCode {
    
    public static func GetExtData () -> String
    {
        return "ExtMethod"
    }
}
```

Can someone helpout on why is the extension methods not being invoked, and how can I invoke it?

Answer (score 0):

calling a swift extension method from c++ is not directly supported.. you have to expose them through a regular method in the Swift class itself or provide a bridge from Swift to C++.
you can provide method in swift class like this

```
import Foundation

public class SwiftCode {

public static func GetClassData () -> String {
    return "classMethod"
}

public static func GetExtData () -> String {
    return "ExtMethod"
}

// You can also provide a method that explicitly calls the extension method.
public static func CallGetExtData() -> String {
    return GetExtData()
}
```

}